# Type 'unknown[]' is missing the following properties from type '[string, unknown]': 0, 1ts(2739)

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am having the error Type 'unknown[]' is missing the following properties from type '[string, unknown]': 0, 1ts(2739) on line 15  at acc.concat([k, ...v.map((s) => `${s} ${k}`)]));

I am new to typescript and this has had me stuck for a while.

I am attempting to convert the json object from an object of form

```
 "message": {
      "arctic":[],
      "atlantic":[
             "north",
             "south",
      ],
      "indian":[],
      "pacific":[
             "north",
             "south",
      ],
      "southern":[],
}
```

to an object of form

```
"message": [
 "artic",
 "atlantic",
 "north atlantic",
 "south atlantic",
 "indian",
 "pacific",
 "north pacific",
 "south pacific",
 "southern"
]
```

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
interface Response {
  statusCode: number
}
interface ListResponse extends Response {
  body: DogList
}
interface DogList {
  message: Array<string> 
  status: string
}
function flat(object:any) {
  return Object
      .entries(object)
      .reduce((acc,[k, v]) => acc.concat([k, ...v.map((s) => `${s} ${k}`)])); //problem here
}

export async function handler(): Promise<ListResponse> {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')

    const payload: DogList = await res.json()
    if (res.ok) {
      const ret:string[]=flat(payload.message)
      return {
        statusCode: res.status,
        body: {
            message: ret,
            status: payload.status
        }
      }
    }
    return {
      statusCode: res.status,
      body: payload,
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: err.code,
      body: {
        message: err.message,
        status: err.status,
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Typescript wants types on the callback function you're passing to the `reduce()`. It looks like `flat()` takes an `Array<string>` and not an `any` so you should correct that first, and then since you've got `Object.entries` and you know the values are strings, you can assign `acc: Array<string>` as well as in the `map()`, `s: String`. With everything properly typed, TS shouldn't have a complaint

Comment: Your DogList does not seem to correctly describe the result of your API, at least compared to the example you gave.